# Change date string format

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I have a date string like so:

```
22-04-2016 8:00:00 AM
```

How do I change the format to `04-22-2016 8:00:00 AM`?

I have tried the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat dateFromString:[cell scheduledDate]]);
```

but this returns `nil`. How can I change the format of this string? `[cell scheduledDate]` is a string.

Comment: A date has no format. A _string_ has a format. What do you actually have, a date or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//Set the AM and PM symbols
[dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"AM"];
[dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"PM"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a"]; 
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[cell scheduledDate]];
```

To get it to an NSDate. Then as matt suggests use another NSDateFormatter to get it to a different string. I agree with his objection but perhaps it is not possible to maintain the information as a date.

Comment: currentDate returns null :( and I am looking to change this back into a NSString after the format has been changed.

Comment: I edited my answer. I was using slashes and had the day and month transposed, should be `@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a"`

Answer (score 3):

If what you have is a string that is supposed to represent a date, and what you want to do is represent that date differently, then you will need, in effect, two date formatters, one to turn the string into a date, and another to turn that date into a new string. (You don't really need two formatters; what you really need is two formats. But it's simpler if you use two formatters.)

Note that the formatter that turns the string into a date must *match* the format of the string you are starting with. Yours does not.

Comment: But please note that it would better if you maintained this information _as a date_. String-to-date-to-string is a Bad Smell.